# Meaning and/or source of polynomials residually of the form $x^n(x-1)$ in Gabber's characterization of Henselian pairs?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Lemma [09XI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09XI) in the stacks project includes a characterization (#5) by Gabber of Henselian pairs $(A,I)$: first, $I\leq \mathrm J(A)$ is contained in the Jacobson radical and second, every monic  $f\in A[x]$ which is residually of the form $x^{\deg f-1}(x-1)\in \frac{A}{I}[x]$ has a root in $1+I$.

The proof uses this condition #5 to prove an $A$-algebra morphism from an étale $A$-algebra to $A/I$ lifts to a retraction of the étale $A$-algebra. The actual source for a polynomial as above is lemma [0EM0](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EM0), whose statement and proof are fairly involved and opaque to me.

**Question.** Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $I\leq \mathrm J(A)$ an ideal contained in the Jacobson radical. Where do monics  $f\in A[x]$ which are residually of the form $x^{\deg f-1}(x-1)\in \frac{A}{I}[x]$ "come from" *conceptually*? Algebraic and geometric answers are both welcome.